# How can I know the number of times 50 foes into my double gp

Tags: javascript, eclipse

ive tried to use modulus but im confused on how to get the right number

```
public double getRewards()
 {
    gp = Math.random() * (1000 - 49 + 1) + 49;
     
     for every 50 spent on groceries a 0.05 discount per gallon of gas
     while(gp/50>49)//trying to get the number of times 50 goes into gp while gp is able to have 50 go into it
     {
         discount++;
         gp=gp/50;
     }
     
     return discount;//returns the amount discounted from your total
 }
```

Comment: Modulus would give you the remainder only, so 207 % 50 = 7. You want to divide and floor the result, so 207 / 50 = 4.14, so `Math.floor(207 / 50)` = 4. No need to iterate and increase a counter each time.

Comment: can you explain floor to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide and [floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (round the number down to the nearest integer) the result. For example: `207 / 50 = 4.14`, and `Math.floor(4.14) = 4`, so `Math.floor(207 / 50)` = 4.

```js
gp = Math.random() * (1000 - 49 + 1) + 49;
     
discountNumber = Math.floor(gp / 50);

discountAmount = discountNumber * 5;

console.log('50 goes into ' + gp + ' ' + discountNumber + ' times, for a savings of ' + discountAmount + ' cents');
```

Comment: ok thanks that helps a tone it is for a class and googling isnt helping so i made an account to help me out